# Pass argument to __init__ of object model class in iterate queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model with overridden `__init__` method like this:

```python
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not kwargs.get('skip', False):
            do_something()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I pass `skip` argument to `__init__`,  when I iter the queryset:

```
data = [obj for obj in MyModel.objects.all()]
```

I would like to implement this via method in custom manager, for use this something like this: `queryset.with_skip()`

Comment: What does `do_something()` do? There might be a better way that overriding `__init__`.

Comment: You could write your own manager(s) and relocate the `do_something()` into your new default-manager.

Comment: @Alasdair, yea, I'm sure it would be better, I read in [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/) about this, that it's not  good idea to override `__init__` method. But in this case, it adds property to model object, that should be use before object will changed. And `do_something` location in `__init__`  method ensures this.

Comment: I still can not imagine the character of do_something() that could be useful before `__init__` if it is well designed. Is it an external interaction (like `pre_init` signal or logging) or data parsing? Is "skip" really a part of data or is it an optimization and you want to read the same object from db sometimes with skip and sometimes with do something? Did you think about tests? Can you do_something in tests safely or must skip? Do you need to read objects with and without skip together by one queryset?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @hynekcer! I used Proxy model for my solution. 
It's actually doesn't matter what was in `do_something`, cause i can't touched that block of code. I made proxy of that model in my block and simple overrided `__init__` method in such a way 

`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, skip=True)`

Thats it!

Comment: @hynekcer `skip` is not part of data. It is mark for ignore the action in `__init__` method. The action of `do_something` making snapshot that did model object every time (after `__init__` btw). But it's needless when we want to simple read data. Yeah, may be it's was bad designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you don't remove the the argument `skip` from `kwargs` before passing it to `super().__init__`. That means that "skip" is a name of field, otherwise you got exception `TypeError("'skip' is an invalid keyword argument for this function")`.

If you really need `do_something()` when the object is created before using so indispensably that nobody should forget to avoid all unsupported ways (??) then custom managers etc. are not enough.

Your problem is that `models.Model.__init__(...)` supports both `*args` and `**kwargs` arguments so perfectly that they should be interchangeable. You broke it and if the "skip" is passed by the complete tuple of positional arguments, you ignore it. That is if the object is created from the database. Read the docs [Customizing model loading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading):

> ... If all of the model’s fields are present, then values are guaranteed to be in the order `__init__()` expects them. That is, the instance can be created by `cls(*values)`...
>   .
>   `|    @classmethod`
>   `|    def from_db(cls, db, field_names, values):`
>   `|        ...`
>   `|        instance = cls(*values)`
>   `|        ...`

An easy way to fix it is to call `do_something()` after `super().__init__` and read `self.skip` instead of implement parsing both kwargs and args.

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        if not self.skip:
            do_something()
```

A problem could be the signal "post_init" that is sent at the end of `super().__init__` if you need it.

The last possibility is to support `*args` (hacky, but still uses documented names someway):

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            skip = kwargs.get('skip', False)
        else:
            # check "val is True" in order to skip if val is DEFERRED
            skip = any(field.name == 'skip' and val is True
                       for val, field in zip(args, self._meta.concrete_fields)
                       )
        if not skip:
            do_something()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**EDIT:** Maybe you you don't need what you wanted and a [Proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) that can do something extra sometimes over a basic model on the same data in the same database table is the right solution. ("Skip" doesn't look like a name describing the object data, but like a name describing a mode of object creation. It is easier to test and maintain a subclass than a mysterious switch inside.)